Spring Boot Test with @MockBean Fails to Mock Mapper
I’m currently working on a Spring Boot application and I’m trying to write a test for my service layer using @MockBean to avoid interacting with the database. Here’s the test code:
//CountCarts Method in CartServiceImpl
//    @Override
//    public int countCarts(Cart cart) {
//        return cartMapper.countCarts(cart);
//    }

@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class CartServiceImplTest {
    @MockBean
    private CartMapper cartMapper;
    @Autowired
    private CartServiceImpl cartService;
    @Test
    void testCountCarts() {
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        int count = 1;
        when(cartMapper.countCarts(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(count);
        assertEquals(count, cartService.countCarts(cart));
        //verify(cartMapper).countCarts(cart);
    }
}

However, the test fails with the following error:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.777 s <<< FAILURE! - in CartServiceImplTest
testCountCarts  Time elapsed: 0.809 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <5>
    at CartServiceImplTest.testCountCarts(CartServiceImplTest.java:46)

It seems like the @MockBean annotation is not working as expected, and the test is still connecting to my database.
Here’s the configuration for my test context:
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"world.xuewei"}, excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(classes = {SpringBootApplication.class})
})
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"world.xuewei.mapper"})
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

In an attempt to solve the problem, I tried removing the @MapperScan(basePackages = {"world.xuewei.mapper"}) annotation. However, this resulted in a different error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addressService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'world.xuewei.mapper.AddressMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup="", name="", description="", authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=java.lang.Object.class, mappedName="")}


I’m at a loss as to how to proceed. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Since you are passed configuration TestApplication to the @SpringBootTest annotation, Spring creates only beans that configured in the TestApplication and some of required beans are missed that's why you see the error about missing beans.
You need to defined all missed beans in the TestApplication or enable component scan to give Spring scan packages.
But I see an ideological problem of the test itself, if you do not plan to test the integration with the database you do not need to use SpringBootTest and create a context. It is much easier to make Unit test with Mockito.
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // or @ExtendWith depends on junit version
class CartServiceImplTest {

private CartMapper cartMapper;

private CartServiceImpl cartService;

@Before
private void setup() {
  cartMapper = Mockito.mock();
  cartService = new CartService(cartMapper);
}

@Test
void testCountCarts() {
    Cart cart = new Cart();
    int count = 1;
    when(cartMapper.countCarts(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(count);
    assertEquals(count, cartService.countCarts(cart));
    //verify(cartMapper).countCarts(cart);
}

}

Thank you for your answer! In fact, I found the solution from another post. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409666/mockbean-and-mybatis-mapper-not-working-together-as-they-did-before-spring-boot)
